# What are some common punctuation errors?

Tags: punctuation

I'm looking for some good "violations" to put on the citation I'm designing to go with my punctuation police costume. ...this is "serious" business, so please don't flag this question.

Answer (score 2):

1. Caring about punctuation too much.
2. Calling punctuation 'grammar'.
3. Mocking people because of how they use punctuation.
4. Failing to ignore Word's squiggly green line.